# Unable to install zoo package (R)

Tags: r, installation, zoo

I am trying to download the zoo package to work with time series using:

```
install.packages("zoo")
```

but I get the following message:

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---  
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/2.12 
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.12  
Warning messages:  
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
  unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80.  
2: In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘zoo’ is not available
```

I tried several different mirrors and I keep getting the same error... Is zoo just not available in most mirrors or is something going wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? And does this happens when you try to install other packages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see [FAQ 2.19](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e).  Or, alternatively, a quick search for "unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80" on [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org).

Reading the FAQ and doing a search for the error will usually help you resolve most issues.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832560/how-do-i-tell-the-r-interpreter-how-to-use-the-proxy-server/18375181#18375181