# Error in HTML parsing in R

Tags: xml, r

I am getting following error in extracting webdata from cricinfo

```
> #Set internet
> Setinternet2=TRUE
> 
> #Loading Libraries
> library(XML)
> library(tm)
> library(RCurl)
> 
> #URL
> URL="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/batting/most_runs_career.html?class=1;id=2010;type=year"
> 
> #HTML parsing
> List=htmlParse(URL)
Error in htmlParse(URL) : 
  error in creating parser for http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/batting/most_runs_career.html?class=1;id=2010;type=year
>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Works for me. When I say 'works', I mean I get a whole bunch of htmlEntityParseRef messages, tag mismatches, and a bunch of other warnings. Do the examples in help(htmlParse) work?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
page <- getURL(URL)
htmlParse(page)
```

You may need options in the call to `getURL` as described in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r/6467744#6467744).