# xmlParse not working

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I am trying to parse the the xml document on the following url:

```
"http://ifis.iowafloodcenter.org/ifis/ws/sites.php?format=xml"
```

Using the following code:

```
library(XML)
ifc=xmlParse("http://ifis.iowafloodcenter.org/ifis/ws/sites.php?format=xml")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
No such file or directoryfailed to load external entity
"http://ifis.iowafloodcenter.org/ifis/ws/sites.php?format=xml"
Error: 1: No such file or directory2: failed to load external entity "http://ifis.iowafloodcenter.org/ifis/ws/sites.php?format=xml"
```

Comment: are u sure? it is working for me

Comment: Yes. It is not working for me. 
I am using proxy for my internet connection. Can this be the reason for not working?
But I can download and install packages.

Comment: I am not sure. But why not trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r ( Acid answer seems to be a good solution)