# R - Read data from HTML table

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to execute an example from book "Practical Data Science Cookbook"
the code as following :

```
year <- 2013

#Acquire offense data
  url <- paste("http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byteam?  group=Offense&cat=Total&conference=NFL&year=season_",
         year,"&sort=530&old_category=Total&old_group=Offense")

offense <- readHTMLTable(url, encoding = "UTF-8", colClasses="character")[[7]]
```

and getting error :

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlNamespaceDefinitions") : 
 no applicable method for 'xmlNamespaceDefinitions' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Please help

Comment: Interesting, I don't get any error (using Windows 7, {XML] 3.98-1.1 and  {RCurl} 1.95-4.3). Maybe you need to update some packages?

Comment: I know what is it ! It could be the proxy definition , because I work in enterprize environment , so how to configure proxy settings for readHTMLTable ?

Comment: would begin to check around these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r

Comment: Look here https://www.google.com/search?q=r+"rcurl"+"proxy"

Comment: Give the `rvest` package a look, it has some great parsing tools that work pretty generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem need to configure http proxy .
On Windows desktop edit R-Studio shortcut , add after R-Studio name
proxy definitions

```
 http_proxy=http://user_id:passwod@your_proxy:your_port/
```

source: [Proxy settings for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r)

Comment: For some URLs like this one, I have to use readHTMLtable( readLines(url),...) or I get that error even with the proxy configured.