# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Couldn't connect to server in R: oauth2.0_token())

Tags: r, curl

```
> github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)

Waiting for authentication in browser...
      Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
      Authentication complete.
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
      Couldn't connect to server
```

I am trying to get the data from GitAPI. I need to Use this data to find the time that the a repo was created. I have tried installing "httpuv" but the error is same.

PS. I am behind a proxy server.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: Try these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
library(httr)    
set_config(use_proxy(url="10.3.100.207",port=8080))
```

This works fine. Thank-you