# Conditioning on connection to server

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to get a HTML code using `httr` and `RCurl` using proxies. The process is using a loop, and so every now and then I get the error message

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Couldn't connect to server

What I would like is to add a condition on this type of error, so that the running of the code won't stop everytime this happens.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285570/error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-couldnt-connect-to-ser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285570/error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-couldnt-connect-to-ser)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem using `tryCatch` and a `while` loop. As long as the function didn't return a specific value, I keep the while loop running.
Explanation on how to use `tryCatch` I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r).