# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Operation was aborted by an application in RStudio

Tags: r

I installed the WHO (World Health Organization) dataset successfully. And run the following code to get the specific data and I got the error message:

```
library(WHO)
WHMDGHIVN <- get_data("MDG_0000000017")
```

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :   Operation
>   was aborted by an application callback

I did the similar code before, and it works and displays the data.
Here is the code I ran successfully:

```
library(WHO)    
WHMDG <- get_data("MDG_0000000016")   
View(WHMDG)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in curl::curl\_fetch\_memory(url, handle = handle) : Couldn't connect to server in R: oauth2.0\_token())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285570/error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-couldnt-connect-to-ser)