# Publishing RShiny app using shinyapps.io?

Tags: shiny, publish, shinyapps

I'm trying to publish my shiny app to shinyapps.io

Instructions online seem to be simple, but when I enter the code from shinyapps.io for my token, I get this response....

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  name lookup timed out
Timing stopped at: 0.013 0.001 10.01
```

Has anyone had this error before and know how to solve it?

Comment: Hi. It will be difficult to solve your problem without a [minimal, reprodubile example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please could you provide one?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285570/error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-couldnt-connect-to-ser presumably related to the internet connection you are using.