# Cannot connect to Quandl via R

Tags: r, quandl

I am trying to pull down data from Quandl using R.  When I try to pull a data series down, I get this message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Couldn't
>   connect to server

I have reviewed similar posts and apparently this is a proxy issue?  I am trying to connect using a company computer.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "999.999.999.999", 
  proxyusername = "mydomain\\myusername", 
  proxypassword = "mypassword", 
  proxyport     = 8080
)
getURL("http://stackoverflow.com", .opts = opts)
```

Original source: [Proxy setting for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r)

There is also a Mac (and presumably Linux) version of the answer there. I would just leave this as a comment but we have multiple unanswered questions on this error so we need to get one with an answer and then dedupe the others.

When using a different function still include  .opts = opts or use the other version of the solution in the linked post, which was

1) Open Terminal and do the following:

```
export http_proxy=http://staff-proxy.ul.ie:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://staff-proxy.ul.ie:8080
```

2) Run R and do the following:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://staff-proxy.ul.ie:8080")
```

Comment: Why not just close as a dupe? I can retract if you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @42 the others with this error message dont have any upvoted or accepted answers, but perhaps just redirecting in this way is good enough