# Rcurl Proxy Authentification in R 3.5

Tags: r, proxy, rcurl

I finally was able to use Rcurl::geturl() by setting  proxyauth ="ntlm", unfortunately when updating R to R 3.5 and Rstudio to the latest version, this all went nuts and i get error ***Authentication failed either because credentials were not provided or they could not be validated***, here is my code:

```
curl=getCurlHandle()
opts <- list(
  proxy         = 'proxy', 
  verbose=T,
  proxyuserpwd = "username:pswd", 
  proxyport     = 80,
  proxyauth ="ntlm",
  httpauth = 1L)

options(RCurlOptions=opts)
getOption("RCurlOptions")
RCurl::getURL("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6467744/6779509) might help you

Answer (score 0):

I succeded by setting

```
proxyauth = 8
```