# R, maps, votos2011.rda

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

Attempting to follow the tutorial on creating maps with R by Oscar Perpiñán Lamigueiro but unfortunately cannot obtain votos2011.rda. The file won't load

Does anyone know where I can obtain this file other than at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40293713/spainVotes/votos2011.rda

Thanks, CC.

Answer (score 0):

The link works for me!
i.e. I can download the file and I can load it into R. Are you trying to do it directly from R? If so try this (which worked for me):

```
tmp <- tempdir()
setwd(tmp)
url <- "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40293713/spainVotes/votos2011.rda"
f <- file.path(tmp,"votos2011.rda")
download.file(url,f)    #File is ~ 462Kb
load(f)
ls()
```

Running the last command I see these objects:

```
[1] "f"         "oldwd"     "tmp"       "url"       "votos2011"
```

Maybe it's your connection?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. Here's the error message:> download.file(url,f)
trying URL 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40293713/spainVotes/votos2011.rda'
Error in download.file(url, f) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40293713/spainVotes/votos2011.rda'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, f) : cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'

Comment: Warning message: In download.file(url, f) : cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'

Comment: Why is the character string of the URL not displaying the http:// part? I am not sure what the problem is, but I suspect it is related to your internet connection (i.e. maybe you need to access a proxy on your network?). What OS are you on? Can you run sessionInfo()

Comment: If you use a proxy server you might need to tell R where to find it. Have a look at this question for further help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4832560/1478381

Comment: Okay, got it this morning in just a couple of seconds. Perhaps it was a prblem with the remote server.

Comment: If you liked the code please feel free to accept it as an answer to your question! Glad it worked for you in the end.