# can't get thru proxy server; tried fixes on SO

Tags: r

On Windows, behind a corporate proxy server which requires password authentication, I tried the approaches listed at [Proxy setting for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r) and [How do I tell the R interpreter how to use the proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832560/how-do-i-tell-the-r-interpreter-how-to-use-the-proxy-server).  When I try to select a mirror, I get:

```
Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "r") : unable to resolve 'cran.r-project.org'
```

I'm pretty sure my username and password are going thru, as I no longer get a message 407(?) telling me that authentication is required.  I got this by setting the value of `http_proxy` either from the console or in the R-properties dialog window.  So, any suggestions as to what else I should try?

Edit: Spacedman:  I typed

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy='username:password@proxyname.company.com:80')`
```

and also tried the same definition string in the R-properties (Windows) dialog box.  Doesn't matter whether I include "http://" in the definition or not; 80 or 8080 same.

Comment: You need to show us exactly what you typed in in order to set the proxy.

Comment: set the proxy in IE, and then call setInternet2(TRUE) in R?

Comment: @richiemorrisroe  So far as i know, I can't load my passwd into IE settings.  W/o authentication, nothing goes.

Comment: It might be a firewall issue. Ask your IT support if they restrict outgoing traffic.

Comment: @James -- you're probably right, so I may be stuck.