# How to tell R to use proxy auto config script (PAC) in Windows

Tags: r, proxy

I am unable to use R functions that connects to another URL on the Internet (e.g. `read_html`, `url.exists`, etc) and getting time-outs etc for pages that I can connect from a browser. I believe this is because R is not using the proxy setting mandated in my office network.

I've looked at another [question on setting proxy for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832560/how-do-i-tell-the-r-interpreter-how-to-use-the-proxy-server) but my situation differs in that we use an auto-configuration script for the proxy.

I have tried setting the below

```
setInternet2(F)
Sys.setenv(http_proxy_user="userid:password")
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://myproxypac.mydomain/proxy.pac")
```

but it didn't work.

Anyone has suggestions on handling PACs in R?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are after, but I usualy set my proxy like this: ```library(httr); set_config(use_proxy(url = "http://yourproxy", port = proxy_port_number))```

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I think that works for direct proxies, i.e. under Windows' LAN Settings selecting "Use a proxy server ..." instead of selecting "Use automatic configuration script", which is my situation.

Comment: Can you post the result of `curl::ie_proxy_info()` and `curl::ie_get_proxy_for_url()` ?

Comment: for `ie_proxy_info`
$AutoDetect
[1] FALSE

$AutoConfigUrl
[1] "http://proxypac.<my.domain>/proxy.pac"

$Proxy
NULL

$ProxyBypass
NULL

Comment: for `ie_get_proxy_for_url` "proxy.<my.domain>:8080"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several internet clients available in R so it depends on what you are using.

A `pac` file is not a proxy server. It is just a piece of JavaScript that the client needs to execute to calculate the required proxy server for a given URL. So your code above is definitely wrong.

Companies use `pac` when different proxy servers are required to connect different hosts (e.g. a special intranet proxy). Have a look at the source code if your pac file to see what's going on. The `curl` package implements an actual PAC client in the `ie_get_proxy_for_url()` function. So you could wrap that to automatically find and set the correct proxy for a curl handle (see also [blog](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/curl-release-0-9-2/)):

```
curl_with_proxy <- function(url, verbose = TRUE){
  proxy <- ie_get_proxy_for_url(url)
  h <- new_handle(verbose = verbose, proxy = proxy)
  curl(url, handle = h)
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
con <- curl_with_proxy("https://httpbin.org/get")
readLines(con)
```

If it turns out your `pac` file simply returns `proxy.<my.domain>:8080` for any URL you might be able to set in an environment variable, but this only works for `libcurl` based clients:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy_user = "userid:password")
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "proxy.<my.domain>:8080")
```

If you can't get it to work, please describe your problem in [this github issue](https://github.com/jeroenooms/curl/issues/1). Perhaps your case can help us improve this part of the `curl` package.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen. How do I find out what internet client that my R is using?

When I tried your suggestion, `proxy <- ie_get_proxy_for_url(url)` threw an error `Error in ie_get_proxy_for_url(url) : 
  ERROR_WINHTTP_UNABLE_TO_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT`

Should I add the above to the github issue at this point, or should we try out more things here first?

Comment: Maybe move to github. Can you test if the url from `ie_proxy_info()$AutoConfigUrl` is actually valid?

Comment: It is, it returns the `PAC` name as listed in the browser config (i.e. `"http://myproxypac.mydomain/proxy.pac"`)

Comment: My bad, I had a malformed value in `url` hence the earlier error; your answer now works perfectly. Thanks!